# Why doesn't Entity Framework 6 select just scope_identity() after insert?

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

When you're saving an entity using EF 6.1, the following SQL Code is generated and executed:

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [dbo].[Customers]([Name], [FirstName])
VALUES (@0, @1)
SELECT [CustomerId]
FROM [dbo].[Customers]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [CustomerId] = scope_identity()',N'@0 nvarchar(max) ,@1 nvarchar(max) ',@0=N'Wenk',@1=N'Manuel'
```

I understand, that the insert/select is done, to retrieve the value of the CustomerId Column immediatley after saving. As far as I know, scope_identity() returns the value, so why isn’t there something like

```
SELECT scope_identity()
```

instead of all that stuff that require physical reads?

Cheers,
Manuel

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you should use more appropriate datatypes than `nvarchar(max)` for columns like "name" and "FirstName"

Comment: Maybe it is to get a result with the correct datatype of the column.

Answer (score 1):

Correct. `scope_identity()` is there to get the generated `CustomerId` value, so EF can use it as entity key. I think, but I have to guess because it's not documented, the `SELECT` is done on the `Customer` table to make sure the retrieved `scope_identity()` really is related to `CustomerId`. There may be cases that an `INSERT` triggers more inserts so `scope_identity()` is allotted to another record.

A second reason to query the `Customer` table is that this query is generated in one method that may also add computed columns to the SELECT clause. It was probably more convenient to query the entity table anyway.

The `WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0` clause is added to make sure that the expected number of rows is affected by the `INSERT` statement. In EF's source code there is a comment:

> Note that we filter on rowcount to ensure no rows are returned if no rows were modified.

Comment: Regarding your "insert triggering more inserts" theory `scope_identity` will never get the identity vale from an insert in another scope such as a trigger. This is the reason for preferring it to `@@identity`

Comment: @MartinSmith No, not in another scope. But maybe there are scenarios in which inserts happen in the same scope. I think they're just being cautious. But getting the correct data type (as you say above) sounds like a good reason to me as well.

Comment: @gert-arnold: Your second guess cannot be the reason because only the id column is selected after insert so it wouldn't get the values of the computed columns. If the first reason would be correct, than an instead-of-trigger that does 3 inserts on the customer table instead of one could lead to a wrong scope_identity(). Couldn't the retrieved value could be wrong than?

Comment: Triggers run in a different scope. And surely when there are computed columns (that are marked as Computed in the EF class model) they would also be selected in the same SQL statement. Nevertheless, I wouldn't mind someone from the EF team to chime in here.