# Insert and Id Read from Entity Framework seems waistful

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

When entity framework inserts into my database it looks like this on my server:

```
exec sp_executesql N'

   insert [order].[MyOrderTable]([SomeOrderValue], [OtherId])
   values (@0, null)

   select [OrderId]
   from   [order].[MyOrderTable]
   where  @@ROWCOUNT > 0 
          and [OrderId] = scope_identity()',

N'@0 bigint',@0=123456
```

This seems like it would be much more efficent written like this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'

   insert [order].[MyOrderTable]([SomeOrderValue], [OtherId])
   values (@0, null)

   select scope_identity() as [OrderId]
   where  @@ROWCOUNT > 0',

N'@0 bigint',@0=123456
```

I know those that made Entity Framework are smart people.  **So I am wondering, why did they decide to hit the table again to look up a value that I already have via `scope_identity()`?**

Comment: [Why doesn't Entity Framework 6 select just scope_identity() after insert?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27680723/861716)

Comment: Would your query work for composite keys?

Comment: @pawel - no, nor would it work if I have calculated columns.  But Entity Framework dynamically generates the SQL.  If there is just an Identity PK (which happens A LOT), then it could use the query above....